# how to redirect page from static class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a static class where I perform my operations. Various operations take place in this class. Here I am using try catch blocks while the transaction is taking place. My code is as below

```
 public static List<Stok> GetIndexStok(string dil,string SubeKodu, string anasayfa,string kisit)
        {
            using (BIRLIKB2BEntities db = new BIRLIKB2BEntities())
            {
                try
                {
                    List<Stok> LST = db.Database.SqlQuery<Stok>("exec [PRC_INDEX_STOK] @dbName, @isAnaSayfa,@Dil,@SubeKodu,@Kisit",
                   new SqlParameter("@dbName", WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SERVER_USER"].ToString()), new SqlParameter("@isAnaSayfa", anasayfa), new SqlParameter("@Dil", dil), new SqlParameter("@SubeKodu", SubeKodu), new SqlParameter("@Kisit", kisit)).ToList();
                    return LST;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw;
                }
              
            }
        }
```

Coming to my question. When there is an error in my code. When the code block catches, I want to redirect the user to the homepage and give the ex message. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Enter your homepage/action name in place of "index" to redirct it.

```
 return RedirectToAction("index");
```

You can also give the controller name if you want to redirect to another controller method.like this :

```
return RedirectToAction("index","controllerName");
```

you can also give it route values too .

Comment: The above code is not in the controller. within the class. So there is no **actionResult**. For this reason **RedirectToAction** is not working

Comment: this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073362/cant-call-response-redirect-inside-a-static-method @AhmetEnesSöylemez

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve here. You should technically handle the exception at your `Controller` level. But you can do a redirect using the current HttpContext `Redirect` property:

```
using System.Web;

public static List<Stok> GetIndexStok(string dil,string SubeKodu, string anasayfa,string kisit)
{
    using (BIRLIKB2BEntities db = new BIRLIKB2BEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            List<Stok> LST = db.Database.SqlQuery<Stok>("exec [PRC_INDEX_STOK] @dbName, @isAnaSayfa,@Dil,@SubeKodu,@Kisit",
                             new SqlParameter("@dbName", WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SERVER_USER"].ToString()), new SqlParameter("@isAnaSayfa", anasayfa), new SqlParameter("@Dil", dil), new SqlParameter("@SubeKodu", SubeKodu), new SqlParameter("@Kisit", kisit)).ToList();
            return LST;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Redirect Here
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("../Login/Login");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A way of doing that is by returning BadRequest with the Exception message
`return BadRequest(ex.message);` then having the front-end code catch the response with something like Ajax, Axios, or something similar and update the View. But this requires you to 'start' the Action by using the same way (using some javascript calls with Ajax)